# How can you find the largest gap in a large grid of numbers?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Hello I have an excel sheet that contains a single massive grid of values, and I want to find the largest gap in the numbers (any of the numbers, not necessarily two adjacent ones). I've seen solutions on here for single columns of data, but I have a massive grid, and I'm almost certain that the number of unique values is greater than the max row count in modern excel, so merging them into a single column won't work. Any ideas on how to make this work even somewhat efficiently?

A few assumptions that can be made in case it's helpful:

- Each column contains no blanks or duplicates
- Each column is sorted in ascending order
- Not all columns are the same length (in fact they may vary wildly)
- The largest gap could easily be between two non-adjacent cells

Both formula and VBA methods are appreciated.

Comment: If each column is sorted in ascending order, you can compare the last row to the first row of each column and then take the maximum of that, correct?

Comment: Each column is sorted in itself only, so you could have column A as 1,3,567,56757 and column B 1,45,65755675. So what I want in this case  is to essentially find the largest difference in the sequence 1,3,45,567,56757,65755675 (in this case 65755675-56757), but I can't just merge the columns like that directly in a separate column because I can't trust that the length won't exceed the row limit.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just loop through all of your columns and count the largest gap like this (I hope this works well I don't currently have Excel, so I just wrote this here, if any errors appear comment it and I will correct my code):

```
Sub LargestGap()
Dim RowCount as Double, ColumnCount as Double, i as Double, j as Double, maxgap as Double
' largest gap
Dim lgc as string
' for performance
Application.Screenupdating=False
' this is just a sample set your columncount to the max columns
ColumnCount = 20
maxgap=0


For i=1 to ColumnCount
  j=0
  do until Cells(i,j+1)=""
    If Cells(i,j)<>Cells(i,j+1) then
      If (Cells(i,j+1)-Cells(i,j)) > maxgap then 
        maxgap=(Cells(i,j+1)-Cells(i,j))
        lgc=Cells(i,j+1).address
      End if
    End if
    j=j+1
  Loop
Next i
Application.Screenupdating=True
' the messagebox will tell you the adress of the largest gap's cell (the first in the bigger)
msgbox(lgc)
End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't quite do what I need. This finds the biggest gap between adjacent cells, but I want the biggest gap between any two cells in the grid. I could probably just loop over all of cells for each cell, but I'd prefer to find something that is less horrible inefficient if it's feasible.

Comment: Yes you are right, I misunderstood your problem, if you really want to make this efficient, I would recommend exporting the table in csv and importing it either in a data analytic tool (that can handle your lenght), or even better in a script you write, this would be pretty easy and efficient to do in python for example.